# Print JavaScript code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't echo the code below because of "" and '' how can I fix this? 
Is there another way to print javascipt code on php without using "" and ''?

```
 print "<a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add to Cart</a>";
```

Comment: yes, look up `heredoc` in php documentation.

Comment: Or just escaping ...

Comment: thanks a lot guys. I think I should study CS/IT abroad because the teaching here in my country is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `"` with a `\`

```
print "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'\">Add to Cart</a>";
```

You can use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
print <<< EOT
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add to Cart</a>
EOT;
```

Another way is to end PHP before the printed line and continue it after:

```
?>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add to Cart</a>

<?php
```